# Destiny 2 error code on PS4 pro

Tags: destiny-2

I keep receiving an error code `ce-34878-0`, this seems to be a common error. I've heard suggestions saying that if I disable HDCP it will reduce the frequency of the error. I have tried disabling it, but I am still experiencing the error at the same frequency.

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: Keep an eye on Bungie's Help Twitter, they're usually providing updates on widespread errors

Comment: yeah I've been watching it.  I'm just curious if anyone has anything else to try since disabling hdcp seems like an odd fix.

Comment: It looks like Bungie themselves have thrown their support in for the HDCP fix, but they're still working on a proper fix.